# Push with Git Bash works, but fails with Git Gui

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-gui, git-bash

I'm hitting a weird roadblock with Git.  I'm trying to push some code to GitHub using Git Gui.  I've done this many times before, but this is the first time on this machine.  I've set up the keys like I've done on my other machines, and added the public key to my GitHub account.  But, here's where things get weird.  I can push just fine using Git Bash, but when I try and push using Git Gui, it fails with the error...

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Like I said, I've done this before and I understand how the keys work, but I just can't figure this issue out.  I've even tested as GitHub suggests, using the command...

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

... and I get the expected response...

```
Hi charlesbihis! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But again, when I try and push with Git Gui, it fails.

**Update**: After posting this question, I saw that there is an [issue opened in Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/issues/detail?id=72) that describes my exact problem.  Perhaps it is a problem with Git Gui itself?

Comment: Any difference between the machine you are trying this on (for the first time,) and the machines you've been able to use with Git Gui before?

Comment: My other machines are Windows and this one's a Mac.  I thought I'd mention it, but figured it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Are there any paths set in the settings file for Git Gui?  (Sorry, I've only used git on the command line... but just thinking that there might possibly be a separate config file for Git Gui?)

Comment: No, I believe Git Gui just uses the existing config files in the .git folder for the project.

Comment: Hmm; if you are using a Mac for this, which Git Gui are you using?

Comment: I installed the same thing as available from http://git-scm.com, except the Mac version.  Particularly, I installed git-1.7.8.4-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg, which is the latest version (as of now) for Snow Leopard.

Comment: Oh, I noticed an issue in Google Code for this project that describes my problem exactly...

http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/issues/detail?id=72

This might be a Git Gui problem then.  Maybe not too :\

Comment: Nice find; since you're using the git-osx package... did your package have a script that was titled "setup git PATH for non-terminal programs.sh" not sure if it's related... still just thinking...

Comment: Yes, there was that script there.  I saw it when I installed Git onto this machine.  I executed it as well, but still no luck :(

Comment: Try running git-gui from a terminal with --trace. On Windows you will need to hit Ctrl-F2 to see the Tk console. --trace causes it to log all the git commands it runs to stderr so we can see what it runs when you try to push.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the newest Git version with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)? Brew has git 1.7.10.2 and git gui on OSX works for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

You caninstall Sourcertree: https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/.
It will use your ssh keys and it should work without any problems.

Make sure to set the ssh to openssh and not to putty.

[image]